# How do I pipe rtl_fm audio to VMware player

Tags: linux

I have Debian Linux (Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux via 'uname -a') installed in a virtual machine using VMware Player on a Windows 7 64 bit laptop. I can play audio from apps in the virtual machine, but I can't seem to find a way to pipe audio from RTL_FM.

I have done some extensive searching, even tried 'man rtl_fm' only to find there is no manual pages for the app. So I am still a bit clueless as to the command line options. I have tried sox, and other options with no success.

I want to play with the CLI settings while listening to the results before I tackle recording to a file. That is my end-goal using a Beaglebone Black and a nooelec R820T SDR dongle.

I hope someone can help me pipe the audio out of my virtual machine to my laptop's audio using RTL_FM so I can explore the command line options.

I am not asking for a 'do it for me' solution. Links to a better understanding on my part would be terrific! I have been searching for hours for a manual on Sox, RTL_FM, and examples of usage via the command line in linux.

This is an embarrassing question really. I have gone through compiling and installing RTL-SDR, the driver for my Realtek USB stick, and figured out that it only works when I plug it into a USB 2.0 port on my laptop. No idea why, but that is what brought me to this issue. To come so far to hit this wall is killing me!

Let me know if there is a config I should post.

Thank you all for your time!!!!

EDIT: I have tried this but no audio...

```
hop@debian:~$ rtl_fm -f 97.9M - | pacat --format=s16le --rate=24000 --channels=1 --latency-msec=100
Found 1 device(s):
  0:  Realtek, RTL2838UHIDIR, SN: 00000001

Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U OEM
Found Rafael Micro R820T tuner
Tuner gain set to automatic.
Tuned to 98152000 Hz.
Oversampling input by: 42x.
Oversampling output by: 1x.
Buffer size: 8.13ms
Exact sample rate is: 1008000.009613 Hz
Sampling at 1008000 S/s.
Output at 24000 Hz.
```

Also tried...

```
rtl_fm -f 97.9e6 -M wbfm -s 200000 -r 48000 - | aplay -r 48k -f S16_LE
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer audio.

Comment: My apologies, I thought this technology was considered part of amateur radio now. Could you suggest a better place? Google search 'rtl-sdr stack exchange' links this version repeatedly.

Comment: The problem is that your question isn't about rtl_fm: it's about playing audio in a Linux VM running in VMware player on a Windows host. The only rtl_fm in the question is that happens to be the program you are running. If you could write the question to be more about rtl_fm and less about all your other software then maybe it would fit here.